# How to minimize an Android application having a TabActivity

Tags: android, tabactivity, minimize

I have an Android application that is a TabActivity with 4 tabs under it. The tabs content is loaded as a new Activity. Now I want to give a button in the application(in all the tab activities) wherein the user can click to send the complete application to background

How can I do that? I have tried moveTaskToBack(true), but it is not working out

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.. If you just start a new Activity (or resume) without closing the current foreground Activity, then it will automatically move to the background.
So I guess the answer is.. do nothing? Just move to another Activity.

Comment: I think I need to explain in a bit more detail, it is actually a media application that play songs. Now a user might want to switch to another application while keeping the song playing(I have a service for that), now there is obviously a home button using which customer can pause my application, however for the users who don't know that, I want to give a button in the app, using which user can select to go to home. Hope i am being clear here. Pls help

Comment: I haven't used Android in a long time, but I believe Services continue running when an Activity is closed. Try making a button that closes your application and test it while playing a song.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just add a button that launches the Home Intent (aka the "Home" button). The Intent is ACTION_MAIN with category CATEGORY_HOME

Answer (score 0):

I know this is coming very late but it may still help someone

Please add the below code to the TabActivity that is hosting other activities and also add the code to every child Activity that is been hosted with the Tabhost. it worked for me.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 5
                && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            Log.d("CDA", "onKeyDown Called");
            onBackPressed();
            return true; 
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
       Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
       setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(setIntent);
    }
```

Best of luck.